# Flutter save the time to a variable when a user accessed a tab

Tags: android, flutter, webview, flutter-layout

Im new to flutter so please bear with me. So I have a simple webview app with 2 tabs

I just wanna ask if how can I save the user load time to a variable name `lastloaded` **in time format** then when the user re-enters that tab, a function will check the `lastloaded` variable if its greater than 1 minute and perform a refresh.

I honestly dont know what to search for this problem. Please assist. Thank you!

if you want to see an example code here:

```
class _CategoriesPageState extends State<CategoriesPage> {
    WebViewController _myController;
      final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            body: WebView(
              initialUrl: 'www.facebook.com',
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
              _controller.complete(controller);
          },
          onPageFinished: (controller) async {
            (await _controller.future).evaluateJavascript("document.getElementsByClassName('footer-container')[0].style.display='none';");
            (await _controller.future).evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('st_notification_1').style.display='none';");
            (await _controller.future).evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('sidebar_box').style.display='none';");

          },
        ),
          floatingActionButton: FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
              future: _controller.future,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> controller) {
                if (controller.hasData) {
                  return FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    controller.data.reload();
                  },
                  child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                );
                }
                return Container();
          }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Use https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences to store in local storage when tab change or tapped

Answer (score 1):

For getting the date and time, User `DateTime` class. Use this class and use the function `difference` to get the difference between DateTimes.

```
var lastLoaded; 
void tappingOnTab(){
   final now = DateTime.now();
   if(lastLoaded != null){
        if(now.difference(lastLoaded).inMinutes > 1){
              // yes last loaded time is more than 1 min ago
        } 
   }
   lastLoaded = now;

}
```

If you want to persist the last loaded time over multiple app instances, use SharedPreferences: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences.

Comment: Hi what do you mean  by"if you want to persist the last loaded time over multiple app instances?"

Comment: Okay i will upvote this one but I still have to experiment how will I do the force refresh of WebView when the condition is met

Comment: btw just wanna ask, there is not yet any save data on lastloaded right ?

Comment: initially the lastLoaded will be `null` and the function assign lastLoaded with current date-time. Then on upcoming calls to the function, the lastLoaded will be last time and it compare with current date-time within the `if()` and assign last loaded again with current date-time

Comment: Okay can we do a pm? I think I ALMOST solve my problem using your solution, since I added a function that will check if internet connection is available.